# how to customise react material menu behaviour

Tags: reactjs, react-native, menu, material-ui

I have a settings button on click of which it should show a menu anchored right to the settings button as shown

[image]

since react material [menu](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/) will do the same job I used menu like below

```
<StyledMenu
            id="customized-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            keepMounted
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}>

        <StyledMenuItem>
            <div style={{ width: '70%', fontSize: '14px', padding: '5px' }}>
                <div>
                    <img src={props.icon} alt='' style={{ width: '18px', height: '18px', }}></img>
                    Brigthness
                </div>
                <div><Slider value={value ? value : 30} onChange={handleChange} aria-labelledby="continuous-slider" /></div>
            </div>
            <div style={{ width: '30%', padding: '5px' }}>
                <div>Reset</div>
                <div><input style={{width:'20px',height:'20px'}} text="om" /></div>
            </div>
        </StyledMenuItem>

 </StyledMenu>
```

**Problem**

- cannot slide smoothly as when I click the slider menu will act as a button
- How to disable the menus button behaviour

[Code sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-v52mf)

Comment: Is it possible to share us a codesandbox with your example ?

Comment: @gionic https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-v52mf

Comment: And what do you want to achieve?  The `StyledMenu` to open smoothly ?

Comment: @gionic the slider should be smoothly scroll able, on clicking menu the ripple effect should not come. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/button) said, you can disable ripple effect

[image]

Please add `disableRipple` property at your `StyledMenu` and `StyledMenuItem`

Check the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-tqtn5).

Comment: @Vikas Acharya is this what you want ?

Comment: I did this and its working fine, but I don't know why the UI is lagging on local project not in code sandbox. apart from that everything else working fine.

Comment: hey i unmarked this as answer. The issue I'm facing is only first time slider will work smoothly and once you released the mouse and try to slide again it wont slide. That's the exact problem I'm facing. In my problem statement I have mentioned 'cannot slide smoothly' can you give some insight on this.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand the problem, could you explain in other words ?

Comment: sorry for my english, The slider is re-rendering multiple times on sliding. because of that the sliding cannot be done. I mean If progress is 5% and if you want to change it to 75% then you can't slide and increase progress. You need to click on 75% position on slider to increase progress. AND THIS BEHAVIOUR CANNOT BE SEEN ON PAGE LOADS FOR THE FIRST TIME. YOU MUST SLIDE FIRST TIME THEN SECOND TIME ONWARD YOU WILL FACE THIS PROBLEM.

Comment: to be more precise this was the problem https://codesandbox.io/embed/k5z4wqmwm7

Comment: Ok I see, but this is a different problem. Let's check it out!

Comment: @VikasAcharya If I understand your problem, I believe that the issue is at the `TableCell` and the way you pass the component. Check this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-sey21) if it's suitable for you.

Comment: Ok, I found that when I replace StyledMenuItem to MenuItem It worked smoothly. anyhow I marked this as answer. But I don't know whats the problem with StyledMenuItem

Comment: You have confused me, this is different again with the above codesandbox.

Comment: The thing is react was working differently in localhost and codesandbox for Menu Items

Comment: Yes ok, but it is different case with the above codesandbox with tableCell and Slider. Anyway.

Comment: I find similar problem somewhere and shared the link.